# YouTube playlists in AMP HTML

Tags: youtube, amp-html

The `<amp-youtube>` extension supports embedding an individual YouTube video but how do you embed a YouTube playlist on an AMP page?

Comment: AMP's amp-youtube element currently only handles individual videos. We should just show these as links or use amp-iframe instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, you cannot use the [`<amp-youtube>`](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/media/amp-youtube) to embed a YouTube Playlist. The `<amp-youtube>` is only used to embed a single/individual video.

A playlist in YouTube has this following form.

https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLlVlyGVtvuVll4Te_6kO4CsI7dcPJKQLt

So instead of `<amp-youtube>`, try to use the [`<amp-iframe>`](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/author-develop/iframes) with it and check if it works.

Comment: This might have changed since this answer was added. See the answer from @Adhy below which works.

Answer (score 3):

Hey just checked it and it works perfectly

this is an Example code playing a video playlist

```
<amp-iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLjwWT1Xy3c4UtTRb5Kysk5NHmggxJc1vw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin" sizes="(min-width: 560px) 560px, 100vw" class="amp-wp-enforced-sizes"><div placeholder="" class="amp-wp-iframe-placeholder"></div></amp-iframe>
```

I tested playing playlist with amp-youtube and it does not work because amp-youtube requires an attribute **data-videoid** this does not work with playlist ID's

Comment: Also we can pass youtube embedding options in src through query params  `https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLjwWT1Xy3c4UtTRb5Kysk5NHmggxJc1vw&controls=1&showinfo=1&modestbranding=1&rel=0`

Answer (score 3):

You can use amp-youtube for playlist like this

```
<amp-youtube
  width="480" 
  height="270"
  layout="responsive"
  data-videoid="FIRST VIDEO ID IS HERE"
  data-param-listType="playlist"
  data-param-list="PLAYLIST ID IS HERE"></amp-youtube>
```

Comment: You are right! This works perfectly. You can even pass the playlist ID in the `data-videoid` field and it will load correctly (the other attributes are required as well).